# How to differentiate between start/stop/status in upstart

Tags: linux, scripting, upstart

upstart has `post-start`, `post-stop`, etc... and `script`.

as i understood, the script part gets executed on `initctl start X` or `initctl stop X` or `initctl status X`.

so how do i know in script which one was called - `start` or `stop`?

Comment: Have you tried if `$1` keeps that information?

Answer (score 0):

The section names say it all: `pre-stop` is happening before job is stopped, and `post-stop` after the job has been stopped. Similarly, `pre-start` is executed before job is started and `post-start` after the job has started.

`script` (or `exec`) section is the main program.

So when starting a job:

- `pre-start`
- `script` or `exec` starts the main executable
- `post-start`

and stopping a job

- `pre-stop`
- the main executable is killed
- `post-stop`

You know which one was called by, well, you're executing certain code you cannot be anywhere else :-)